# Checkbox com function

Tags: javascript, formulário, checkbox

Boa tarde, estou montando um formulário com checkboxes que chamam uma `function` através do `onclick`

```
<body> 
    <form name="questao1" method="post" onsubmit="sendToDB();"> 
        <br><input type="checkbox" name="Q1[]" value="Enfermagem" onclick="getPontos(1)"> Garantir a saúde das pessoas 
        <br><input type="checkbox" name="Q1[]" value="Eletroeletronica" onclick="getPontos(2)"> Máquinas e instalações elétricas.
        <br><br><input type="submit" value="Próximo" onclick="finalizar()">     
    </form>
</body>
```

Para executar essa função:

```
    function getPontos(pontos){

                efmg = 0;
                eltelt = 0;
                info = 0;
                alm = 0;
                pltc = 0;
                log = 0;
                adm = 0;
                qmc = 0;
                ma = 0;

                if (pontos == 1){ efmg = efmg + 1; }   
                if (pontos == 2){ eltelt = eltelt +1; }

}

function finalizar(){   
           if(efmg>eltelt){alert('Enfermagem');}else{alert('Eletroeletronica');} 
        }
```

Porém, toda vez que chamo essa função os valores voltam a valer zero, e eu preciso que o valor se mantenha para a clique do próximo checkbox. o problema, é que se eu não atribuir os valores iniciais como zero, a função não funciona, e o finalizar não exibe resultado algum. Alguém pode me ajudar a resolver? Agradeço desde já :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize variaveis globais, fora da sua funcao, que inicializam como 0 quando a pagina é carregada, e cada vez que a função for chamada eles modificam o valor dessas variáveis.

```
var efmg = 0;
var eltelt = 0;
var info = 0;
var alm = 0;
var pltc = 0;
var log = 0;
var adm = 0;
var qmc = 0;
var ma = 0;

function getPontos(pontos){

            if (pontos == 1){ efmg = efmg + 1; }   
            if (pontos == 2){ eltelt = eltelt +1; }

}

function finalizar(){   
       if(efmg>eltelt {alert('Enfermagem');}else{alert('Eletroeletronica');} 
    }
```

Algo que me ocorreu quando estava vendo tambem, voce nao esta inicializando as variaveis dentro da funcao (var xxx, var yyy), entao imagino que faz isso em outro lugar do codigo, podes inicializar como 0 logo ali.

Comment: Ook, fiz isso, porém ainda não funciona, acredito que o erro esteja agora na parte de php xP:

Comment: Mas você entendeu o que estava acontecendo de errado ne? Caso tenha mais duvidas no PHP, te recomendo criar outro topico.

Comment: SIm, obrigada :)

Comment: @RafaZanezi se essa resposta resolveu sua dúvida inicial, marque ela como solução no canto esquerdo.